# USB C DP Alt Mode external monitor

Tags: display

I just bought a new dell XPS 13 for work and everything is working smoothly except the external monitor and it's pretty annoying to be tied to the small 13 inch display

I bought an usb C to HDMI cable with thunderbolt 3 support, tested it with my phone and it works on my hdmi screen

but when I plug my laptop I have no signal message

when I run `lspci -tv` with the display plugged, I got :

> +-1c.4-[03-6d]----00.0-[04-6d]--+-00.0-[05]--
>              |                               +-01.0-[06-38]--
>              |                               +-02.0-[39]----00.0  Intel Corporation JHL6540 Thunderbolt 3 USB Controller (C step) [Alpine Ridge 4C 2016]
>              |                               -04.0-[3a-6d]--

when I run `xrandr -q` I have

> Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 3840 x 2160, maximum 8192 x 8192
>   eDP-1 connected primary 3840x2160+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 294mm x 165mm
>
> DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
>
> DP-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)

any clue on how to get external display working ?

Comment: Is the output of `xrandr -q` any diferent when it's unplugged? Also, do you know whether your external monitor is DisplayLink or DisplayPort?

Comment: xrandr -q output is the same when it's unplugged.
the monitor I used to test is a regular tv, so I thing it's a DisplayLink

Comment: Do you happen to have the model of cable handy?

Comment: yep
https://www.amazon.fr/3-1-type-Thunderbolt3-Compatible-Chromebook-V30-1-8-BeckenBower/dp/B0791MGDP6/ref=mp_s_a_1_3?__mk_fr_FR=%C3%85M%C3%85Z%C3%95%C3%91&qid=1545824464&sr=8-3&pi=AC_SX236_SY340_QL65&keywords=thunderbolt3%20hdmi&dpPl=1&dpID=41VGQ81NtpL&ref=plSrch&fbclid=IwAR2eO5KhJI6Z8DUbK4IPipf5NLlN03Uw4h-zP1IbqXYt1mIiY9L5RLgmH9M

Answer (score 1):

From your Amazon link in the comments, you appear to have a DP Alt Mode cable, which essentially uses USB C Port for DisplayPort protocol output, which would make use of your regular video card. I believe (but am not positive) that on a Dell XPS 13, that should be an Intel driver. It should, at any rate, show up as one of your `DP*`-devices, but is not.

Based on that, you might see if [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/546818/displayport-monitor-not-detected-if-switched-off-and-on-again) from AskUbuntu is helpful. Another debugging steps you could take care:

- See whether it works in Windows; if it doesn't, it's perhaps not supported at all.
- Try booting up with the DisplayPort already connected, to see if it's a life detection issue.

You could also try using a DisplayLink cable, which would have different drivers. In general when you Google this, if I were you, I'd search for Ubuntu (on which Elementary is based) and "DP Alt Mode", which is what your cable uses.

Comment: Thank you for your relply, I'll try those steps later and update this post if I figure out how to solve this issue.